# How to send custom parameter to citruspay in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, citrus-pay

I want to pass custom parameter as **id** while transaction on citrusPay and want that custom parameter **(i.e. id)** in response also.

Does anyone knows have i can achieve this in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. That is done using customParameters.

Check this https://developers.citruspay.com/documentation/mobile-payments/unified-mobile-sdk/sdk-features-2/pass-additional-parameters-via-bill-url/

Comment: I have appended custom parameter on billUrl but it give me an error as  - 
Invalid JSON data : Value of required model key value is null

Comment: There might be a key that you would be missing. Can you check?